# send URL to detail view with button selection in master view

Tags: xcode

I am trying to make master-detail view with generic webview in detail where the URL changes with selection of button in master view controller. Obviously I'm a novice and I need help!

in master view mfile I send through button like this:

```
-(IBAction)myButton1:(UIButton *) sender {
[self.detailVC location:@"http://google.com"];
}

-(IBAction)myButton2:(UIButton *) sender {
[self.detailVC location:@"http://yelp.com"];
}
```

in detail view mfile I have:

```
-(void)location(NSString *)myLocation{
_theLocation = myLocation;
}

-(void) viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.theLocation];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURL Request requestWithURL:videoURL];
[self.webview loadRequest:request];
}
```

I am getting no build errors, but none of the URL's are loading. Please help!

Comment: Why not just declare the location with `@property` and then set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know `- (void)viewDidLoad Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory` , in your issue, it seems the self.detailVC is always alive in memory, that should not call `viewDidLoad`.

you can update the web view in `- (void)setLocation(NSString *)myLocation` directly:

```
- (void)setLocation(NSString *)myLocation
{
    _location = myLocation;
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.location];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURL Request requestWithURL:videoURL];
    [self.webview loadRequest:request];
}
```